# Can't install Eclipse Valgrind plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation

I'm trying to install Valgrind (0.4.0) plugin in Eclipse from technology.linuxtools Update Site (http://download.eclipse.org/technology/linuxtools/update) but I get the following error:

> Cannot complete the request.  See the
>   details. Cannot find a solution
>   satisfying the following requirements
>   org.eclipse.swt [3.4.1.v3449c].

According to "About plugins", my Eclipse has version 3.4.2 installed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's seems that your Eclipse installation is missing SWT Tools.
So before to install Valgrind, start by installing SWT using this update site:

http://www.eclipse.org/swt/updates/3.5

Restart Eclipse after the installation process and try to install Valgrind again.